# Bluetooth a2dp connection state changed event not fired

Tags: android

I'm trying to receive a broadcast when an a2dp device is connected/disconnected but somehow the receiver is not called - this did work earlier today, then I changed some things and it didn't work anymore, I changed it back and it still doesn't work :(

My manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />

<receiver
    android:name=".CsoBtConnChanged"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED" />
        <action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The adapter state change does work

```
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED
```

but

```
android.bluetooth.a2dp.profile.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
```

and

```
android.bluetooth.adapter.action.CONNECTION_STATE_CHANGED
```

do not?

Comment: Okay I got it working by creating a new receiver and adding just the a2dp profile action in the manifest. Wtf?? So I guess the problem is solved but the question is not answered..?

Comment: Did you make it work ? Even when I just keep the a2dp connection state, my receiver is not fired ...

Comment: Well yes but i have no idea why

Comment: Thanks man, I got it working, I made a typo when writing the action name !